# Changing the plot axes values

Tags: plotting

I had an equation in which I replaced two of my variables `k` and `n` with their logarithmic counterpart variables `logk` and `logn` as follows :

```
eq = (Binomial[n, 2]*(3.97887*10^-10 Cos[200 k ArcSinh[50/k]])/
       Sqrt[1 + 2500/k^2] == -0.00003 // Rationalize) /. {n -> 
    10^logn, k -> 10^(-logk)}
```

Then I solved for one of the variables `logn` :

```
solk[logn_] := 
 logk /. NSolve[{(1.9894350000000002`*^-10 10^logn (-1 + 10^logn) Cos[
          200 (10^-logk)* ArcSinh[5*10^2 (10^logk)]])/
       Sqrt[1 + (25*10^2 10^(2 logk))] == -(3/10000), -65 < logk < 0},
     logk, Reals][[1]]
```

And finally plotted :

```
p1 = Plot[2.0*solk[logn], {logn, 0, 23}, 
  PlotRange ->All]
```

The plot I get has the y-axes and x-axes values as the powers of `10` (since my base of log is 10).

I just want to convert to the normal values i.e. for example instead of showing `0,1,2,..,23` on x-axis I would like to show `10^1, 10^2,..., 10^23` How can I do this?

The answer could be in either of two formats :-

i)  Truly converting the x and y values to decimal scale and showing as such on the plot

ii) Merely a relabelling of the values shown on the axis.

It seems trivial but I can't figure it out!

Note : A small caveat is to note that I have values which range upto `10^23` in the calculation and I can't just use `k` and `n` instead of `logk` and `logn` because of some reason.

Comment: Ummm... what is logn?  What is logk?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It is mentioned in the first codeblock. Basically `n = 10^logn` and `k=10^-logk`. They are just scaled variables related to `n` and `k`